# what can be called from -fini function of shared library?

Tags: c, gcc, gnu, ld

I am using a shared library with `LD_PRELOAD`, and it seems that I can't call some functions from the function set with `-fini=` `ld` option.  I am running Linux Ubuntu 20.04 on a 64-bit machine.

Here is the SSCCE:

`shared.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

gcc -shared -fPIC -Wl,-init=init -Wl,-fini=fini shared.c -o shared.so

LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/shared.so whoami
```

`shared.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void init() {   
    printf("%s\n", __func__);
    fflush(stdout);
}

void fini() {
    int printed;
    printed = printf("%s\n", __func__);
    if (printed < 0)
        sleep(2);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

When I call `./shared.sh` , I get

```
init
mark
```

and 2 second pause.

So it seems `printf()` fails in `fini()` but `sleep()` succeeds (`errno` values are not specified for `printf`, so I don't check it)  Why and what kind of functions can I call from `fini`?   `ld` manpage does not say anything about any restrictions.

Comment: It's likely that the global `FILE *` for `stdout` has not been initialized, or is not yet associated with an underlying file descriptor.

Comment: @BrettHale not sure if I understand you - the problem is in `fini`, not in `init` . So OK, you are going to say, `stdout` is _already_ gone when `fini` is called. Well, but first, it would be explained in `ld` manpage, that you cannot call this function from `fini`, and second, then what else can I not call, how to tell? Suppose I call something and it works for me, but, at the customer site, it does not? Not good.

Comment: My mistake - I mixed up the `init` and `fini` function results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initialization functions of each dynamically linked component are executed in the order in which the components are loaded. In particular, if A depends on B but B does not depend on A, then B's initialization functions run before A's. The termination functions of each dynamically linked component are executed in the order in which the components are unloaded. In particular, if A depends on B but B does not depend on A, then B's initialization functions run after A's. Generally, termination functions run in reverse order from initialization functions, but I don't know if that's true in all cases (for example when there are circular dependencies). You can find the rules in the [System V ABI specification](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/gabi4+/ch5.dynamic.html#init_fini) which Linux and many other Unix variants follow. Note that the rules leave some cases unspecified; they might depend on the compiler and on the standard library (possibly on the kernel, but I think for this particular topic it doesn't matter).

A shared library loaded with `LD_PRELOAD` is loaded before the main executable, so its initialization functions run before the ones from libc and its termination functions run after the ones from libc. In particular, libc flushes standard streams and closes the file descriptors for the output streams. You can see this happening by tracing system calls:

```
$ strace env LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/shared.so whoami
…
write(1, "gilles\n", 6gilles
)               = 6
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, {tv_sec=2, tv_nsec=0}, 0x7ffc12bd2df0) = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

The call to `clock_nanosleep` is `sleep(2)`. The calls to `printf` and `fflush` happen just before; since stdout has been closed, they do nothing and return -1. Check the return value or use a debugger to confirm this.

Contrast with what happens if `shared.so` is linked normally, rather than preloaded.

```
$ cat main.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    puts("main");
    return 0;
}
$ gcc -o main main.c -Wl,-rpath,. -Wl,--no-as-needed -L. -l:shared.so
$ ./main
init
main
fini
```

Here, since `main` loads `shared.so`, the shared library is initialized last and terminated first. So by the time the `fini` function in `shared.so` runs, libc hasn't run its termination functions and the standard streams are still available.

Comment: Thank you. I did check return of `printf` and it shows negative (error), the problem is, by the standard, `printf` errno values are undocumented.

Comment: thank you, you helped me much, can I possibly ask you one thing.  What I _really_ need `fini` is of course, not debug prints, but I create an anonymous pipe (a pair of file descriptors), from a program, communicate the file descriptor number to the shared library, and then, at `fini` time, I want the shared library to write data to that descriptor, that my main program will receive.  This seems to work now. Can you think a scenario where that functionality could too be shut down before `fini` time. From my research following your answer, no, but you know more.

Comment: @MarkGaleck POSIX does specify `errno` values for `printf` including `EBADF`. Using an pipe created inside the `fini` function should work even in a preloaded library: you're not relying on things set up for the duration of the `main` function.

Comment: sorry I oversimplified. `main` program creates blocking anonymous pipe, puts the write end descriptor of the pipe, in an env variable, and `LD_PRELOAD` is another env variable. Prog then `fork execve` another, preloading the lib. The lib `init` receives the descriptor. `fini` writes data to the descriptor. `main` prog reads the data (without waiting for the child :) - that's important because of limit of pipe capacity, and also blocking pipe). Appears to work, and should always work based on timing of `init` and `fini` ?